# How to create a matrix with some conditions?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I want to create an $n \times n$ matrix (eg. $n=5$) using the following steps:

1) The entries aii (i = 1, ..., n) that form the main diagonal of a square matrix are 0 (aii=0); In *C++*, the element of matrix is generate `if(i==j){M[i][j]=0}`. In *Mathematica*:

```
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0},{n,n}]
```

2) Generates a random integer number in the interval [1,i-1] with uniform distribution. Using *Mathematica*:

```
z = RamdomInteger[{1,i-1}]
```

3) The off-diagonal elements are zero or 1 as follows:

a) {i_,j_}->{z,j} with probability 0.9 or {i_,j_}->1-{z,j} with probability 0.1

b) {j_,i_}->{j,z} with probability 0.9 or {j_,i_}->{j,z} with probability 0.1

In *Mathematica*:

```
{i_,j_}->RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{{z,j_},1-{z,j_}}]

{j_,i_}->RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{{j_,z},1-{j_,z}}]
```

So

```
    s = SparseArray[{z=RamdomInteger[{1,i-1}],{i_, i_} ->  0, 
            {i_,j_}->RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{{z,j_},1-{z,j_}}],
            {j_,i_}->RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{{j_,z},1-{j_,z}}]},{n,n}]
```

There is error in language.  How to solve?

Comment: You're not supposed to have underscores on the right hand side of a rule, for one.

Comment: You have spelled `RandomInteger`  as `RamdomInteger` with a 'm' instead of 'n'

Comment: a `SparseArray` can not hold lists as elements.  `RandomChoice` can not take lists as weights. It is really unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what you are trying to do (e.g., how is `{z,j}` supposed to stand for either `0` or `1`, as you suggest?), but I believe a general answer to your general question is possible.  The key is to separate out what you are trying to produce as values into a function of the indexes.  Here is an example, which is intended to echo your problem in key ways (without matching it):

```
f[i_, j_] := With[{z := RandomInteger[i - 1]},
  If[i > j, Boole[z > j], 0]
  ]
s=SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i != j -> f[i, j]}, {n, n}]
```

Note that the default value is `0`, so you don't need to place the zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: For example, I will build point-to-point until you reach a 3x3 matrix:

Comment: For i=1 (associate j=1) f[1][1]=0

Comment: 2) For i=2 (2 values associated with j). Generates a random integer number in the interval [1,i-1]; z=RandomInteger[{1,i-1}]=1
f[i=2][j=1]=RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{f[z=1][1],1-f[z=1][1]}]
f[i=2][j=2]=0
f[j=1][i=2]=RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{f[j=1][z=1],1-f[j=1][z=1]}]
f[j=2][i=2]=0

Comment: 3) For i=3,  generates a random integer number in the interval 
z=RandomInteger[{1,i-1}]=(1 or 2). Suppose the draw is z=2
f[i=3][j=1]=RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{f[z=2][j=1],1-f[z=2][j=1]}]
f[i=3][j=2]=RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{f[z=2][j=2],1-f[z=2][j=2]}]
f[i=3][j=3]=0 
f[j=1][i=3]=RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{f[j=1][z=2],1-f[j=1][z=2]}] 
f[j=2][i=3]=RandomChoice[{0.9,0.1}->{f[j=2][z=2],1-f[j=2][z=2]}]  
f[j=3][i=3]=0

Comment: you should *edit the question* with clarifying information.  An example expected output might be useful as well (I'm still confused by the "off-diagonal elements are zero or 1" part )